# How to complete a dpkg cuBLAS Patch Update to CUDA 8 installation in 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, cuda

I'm new to Ubuntu. I downloaded cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb for Ubuntu 16.04 from the official [CUDA Toolkit Download | CUDA Developer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) website.

I ran these two commands from the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

What is the name of the package required to install to complete the installation?

```
sudo apt-get install <name?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-cublas-performance-update_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Update the PATH variable to include the CUDA binaries folder. To update it, edit the `/etc/environment` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

After editing the `/etc/environment` file will look like this.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin"
```

If there are other locations in your PATH don't remove them, leave them in the PATH too.

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Validate the CUDA installation.

```
nvcc --version
```

The results of `nvcc --version` should show that NVIDIA Cuda is installed.

Comment: You probably need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH too, to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
 (or add it to an existing LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

Answer (score 9):

In certain cases an install will don't work because the package is already installed.

Instead of install, just do an upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade cuda
```